# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null Parameter name: value - How to fix this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Please help! I am getting error in the line :
`details.NominalVoltage = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.NominalVoltage?.ToArray());`

I have below code in my builder.

```
foreach (var panel in panelAddresses.Take(2))
                {
                    var paneldetails = new SM_NFPA72ReportPage1();
                    details.batteryDetails = new List<Battery>();
                 
                    var AssociatedPrimaryPowers = new Repository(new BuildConnection()).GetPanelPrimarypowerDevcies(reportInput.UseroId, panel, reportInput.BuildingId, reportInput.TestSessionId[0]).Result;
                    AssociatedPrimaryPowers.ForEach(x => paneldetails?.batteryDetails?.Add(new Battery
                    {
                        NominalVoltage = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "nominalVoltage")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                        NominalAmps = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "nominalAmps")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                        NominalLocation = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "disconnectLocation")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                        Protection = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "overCurrentType")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                        ProtectionAmps = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "overCurrentAmps")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                        ProtectionLocation = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "powerLocation")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
                    }));
                    details.NominalVoltage = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.NominalVoltage?.ToArray());
                    details.NominalAmps = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.NominalAmps?.ToArray());
                    details.NominalLocation = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.NominalLocation?.ToArray());
                    details.Protection = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.Protection?.ToArray());
                    details.ProtectionAmps = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.ProtectionAmps?.ToArray());
                    details.ProtectionLocation = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.ProtectionLocation?.ToArray());
                }
```

Below attached is my model for above builder:

```
public class SM_NFPA72ReportPage1 : IReportModel
    {
        public string NominalVoltage { get; set; }
        public string NominalAmps { get; set; }
        public string NominalLocation { get; set; }
        public string Protection { get; set; }
        public string ProtectionAmps { get; set; }
        public string ProtectionLocation { get; set; }
        public List<Battery> batteryDetails { get; set; }
        public List<PanelDetailsInfo> panelInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

I am reusing the Battery model to fetch the values from repository

```
 public class Battery
    {
        public string NominalVoltage { get; set; }
        public string NominalAmps { get; set; }
        public string NominalLocation { get; set; }
        public string Protection { get; set; }
        public string ProtectionAmps { get; set; }
        public string ProtectionLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy here the error message you see and indicate when you see it (build vs run). if it fail at runtime, also include an example of the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens if `paneldetails` or `paneldetails.NominalVoltage` is `null`? In that case, you'll call `string.Join(", ", null)`, but that's not valid -- you can't join `null` together. You'll need to decide what you want to do if it is null: do you want an empty string, `null`, something else?

Comment: @Loda : Title of this question has exception i got.

Comment: That said, you're taking something which isn't an array, such as `string NominalVoltage`, and calling `ToArray()` on it. This will work, but it will split on every character, so your e.g. calling `string.Join(", ", "Test".ToArray())` will result in `"T,e,s,t"`. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @canton7 : I need to fetch only first two elements and display it as comma separated. that is why i have used string.join()

Comment: @canton7 : No! I want the result to be displayed like NominalVoltage1 , NominalVoltage2.                                                                                                                       If there only one value the, display only NominalVoltage1

Comment: This issue is caused by null data, you can only solve it by yourself to debug the code which line and which variable is null. Pls check the `paneldetails` and `paneldetails.NominalVoltage`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you that the parameter value is null, that should mean that:

```
paneldetails?.NominalVoltage?.ToArray()
```

...gives you a null result, and that the `string.Join` method does not accept it.
You need to make sure that you do not provide a null value to the method.

This can be achieved in multiple ways, for example by checking for null value before calling the method:

```
if (panelDetails?.NominalVoltage != null)
{
    details.NominalVoltage = String.Join(",", paneldetails.NominalVoltage.ToArray());
}
```

or by returning a empty array by default if it is null:

```
details.NominalVoltage = String.Join(",", paneldetails?.NominalVoltage?.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<string>());
```

Comment: NominalVoltage = deviceDetailsList?.CustomProperty?.Where(y => y.fieldName == "nominalVoltage")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,                                                                                         I think this line of code is not returning value. Instead of using FirstOrDefault() is there any other function which provide mutiple values??